# App not compatible with buildpack, django Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, django, heroku

Using buildpack: heroku/python but still it says not compatible. I am a beginner in Django please help.

Here is build log :

-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
!     Push failed

Answer (score 0):

There might be tons of reasons related to your problem. Please consider using [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration) to learn how to deploy Django applications. You should initially define `Procfile` (probably `runtime.txt` file) and `requirements.txt` files at the minimum. Please make sure your `requirements.txt` file contains all the requirement (also related to deployment/process packages such as gunicorn or similar). You can also share more detail if you want to get specific answers related to your problem.